# How to see progress on my moderator intervention flags

Tags: discussion, flags

I clicked on the *in need of moderator intervention* flag. How do I get an update on this flag, to know who accepted it or who rejected it real time?

Comment: Go to your [profile's activity tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5336818/yo-yo?tab=topactivity) and click on the helpful flags link.

Comment: What do you mean by "who rejected it real time"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see part of this in your [flag summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5336818) - you'll only see the status of your flag (helpful = accepted, declined = rejected). You *can't* see *who* did this - sometimes, it's a result of a review by 'normal' users, sometimes, flags have been handled by moderators. You can distinguish custom flags by the fact that the text you entered is displayed; for other flags you'll see the name ('not an answer', 'very low quality', etc.). *Real-time* feedback on flags (e.g. via the Inbox or the Achievements) is not possible.